# Can PhpStorm make a check of if the project is opened in the browser or not?

Tags: php, phpstorm

I work in PhpStorm. When in project I click "Run", it runs in browser. But sometimes if I play "Run" often, there is no end of tabs in browser. Can PhpStorm make a check of if the project is opened in the browser or not? And just refresh the browser page if it's opened.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do, and there is only 1 tab open at all times - although it is nested within the IDE.

- Run > Edit configurations
- Press the green arrow in the top left and add Chromium Remote

[image]

- After that you can press `Alt + Shift + F10` (Run) and a pop-up box should appear. Select your Chromium Remote

[image]

- Now you should have a window appear in your IDE and now you can run your files with the run toolbar at the top and they'll appear in the Chromium Remote window.

[image]